# Deploying a Replica Set

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB. I am trying to create a Replica Set for testing and development. It shows me the message in the picture!

[image: screenshot]

I followed the steps shown in the official documentation:

[Deploy a Replica Set for Testing and Development](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-for-testing/)

What is the problem please ?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Try to rephrase your question. Tell *us* what the problem seems to be (include the error output as text instead of screenshots), and maybe someone will be able to help you with a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 32-bit OS and 32-bit builds do not support the WiredTiger storage engine.

You need to use either 64-bit or change your storage engine to mmapv1 as suggested in screenshot by passing parameter explicitly. *--storageEngine=mmapv1*

check here https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you installed the 32-bit version of MongoDB, and are attempting to use the WiredTiger storage engine.  They are not compatible.  See [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/#faq-32-bit-limitations).  You'll need to reconfigure your install to use mmapv1 instead.